# Error in socketConnection in SSDM (from R)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, bioinformatics

I am currently running a stacked species distribution model through a linux cluster using the following code:

```
library(SSDM)

setwd("/home/nikhail1")

Env <- load_var(path = getwd(), files = NULL, format = c(".grd", ".tif", 
".asc",
                                                     ".sdat", ".rst", ".nc", 
".envi", ".bil", ".img"), categorical = "af_anthrome.asc",
            Norm = TRUE, tmp = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)

Occurrences <- load_occ(path = getwd(), Env, file = 
"Final_African_Bird_occurrence_rarefied_points.csv", 
                    Xcol = "decimallon", Ycol = "decimallat", Spcol = 
"species", GeoRes = FALSE,
                    sep = ",", verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)
head(Occurrences)
warnings()
SSDM <- stack_modelling(c("GLM", "GAM", "MARS", "GBM", "RF", "CTA", 
"MAXENT", "ANN", "SVM"), Occurrences, Env, Xcol = "decimallon",
            Ycol = "decimallat", Pcol = NULL, Spcol = "species", rep = 1,
            name = "Stack", save = TRUE, path = getwd(), PA = NULL,
            cv = "holdout", cv.param = c(0.75, 1), thresh = 1001,
            axes.metric = "Pearson", uncertainty = TRUE, tmp = TRUE,
            ensemble.metric = c("AUC", "Kappa", "sensitivity", 
"specificity"), ensemble.thresh = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75), weight = TRUE,
            method = "bSSDM", metric = "SES", range = NULL,
            endemism = NULL, verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE, cores = 200)

save.stack(SSDM, name = "Bird", path = getwd(),
       verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)
```

I receive the following error message when trying to run my analyses:

```
Error in socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking 
= TRUE,  : 
all connections are in use
Calls: stack_modelling ... makePSOCKcluster -> newPSOCKnode -> 
socketConnection
```

How do i increase the maximum number of connections? Can i do this within the `SSDM` package as `parallel` is built in. Do I have to apply a specific function from another package to ensure that my job runs smoothly across clusters?

Thank you for you help,
Nikhail

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you also add the output of `sessionInfo()` to the question (another code block at the bottom for it is fine). It'll help narrow down the type of system, which is likely necessary since this is probably going to be a tweak of an OS-level setting.

Comment: I've since tried running the code using just 19 cores. This does not produce an error, although will increase computing time

Comment: The output of sessions info: R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /apps/R/R-3.4.3-gcc/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /apps/R/R-3.4.3-gcc/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of open connections you can have in R is 125. To increase the number of connections you can have open at the same time, you need to rebuild R from source. See
https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/28